# How to learn professional JavaScript in two days?

Tags: javascript, web

I really need to learn professional javascript in two days because I am gonna have to hit the
ground running (real world project). I have little which can be approximated to no knowledge of JavaScript or website development. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Not possible. 1st day: Oh it is so simple, awesome! 2nd day: WTF? Why is there a == operator? Why do I need to use hacks for IE? WTF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646032/whats-the-best-javascript-tutorial

Comment: @M28 3rd day: Why is there a === operator? 4th day: Where's the ==== operator?

Comment: wait, there isn't a ==== operator... I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: I guess you should learn some language-specific JavaScript features? or get a JavaScript cheatsheet? http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Functional_Javascript

Comment: Define your own `hours_in_day`. Make it like 125 or something. Just wondering...why are you being forced to "hit the ground running" on a project that you can't [based on what you've said] really contribute to?

Comment: I suggest you do some research on relativity and find how to slow down time .May be you could convert yourself to photon particle and travel @ speed of light. Although I am not sure if you can read up and learn something, while zipping across galaxies. Wait a minute, why do you want to learn javascript when you invented on how to travel in the speed of time, that would be mental.

Comment: If you can complete this in two days https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 36):

[image: teach yourself]

Seriously, two days is about enough to get a feel for the basics. It's nowhere near enough time to get to "professional" level (whatever that means exactly). The more experience you have with other languages, the easier it will be, though.

Answer (score 2):

Don't cram for a programming language, especially learning it *professionally*, unless you have previous programing experience.

Comment: I do have some programming experience in java C++ but none in this sort of programming. Dont know where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

http://eloquentjavascript.net/

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744906/would-you-recommend-starting-from-html5-css3-for-beginners for resources on learning web technologies.

Answer (score 2):

Go through video lectures by Douglas Crockford at http://yuiblog.com/crockford/. You could be able to get rid of some assumptions, misconceptions and pick up some really good concepts in less than 10 hrs of video.

Nevertheless, it is indeed a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

This article is a great source of up to date, modern JavaScript resources:
http://blog.reybango.com/2010/12/15/what-to-read-to-get-up-to-speed-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to learn JavaScript, you can follow these courses if you have little previous programming experience. They are interactive and you can code all the examples in the explorer (and they are free).

1 - [JavaScript Fundamentals](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript-upgraded)
2 - [JavaScript](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript)

And finally, a library called jQuery to make a little bit easier JavaScript programming.

3 - [jQuery](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery)

This won't take you to days, but is a good beginning to be a JavaScripter.

Good luck.